# Thinking sphinx updates delta index even when no fields are updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, thinking-sphinx, update-attributes, delta

Even when no fields specified in update attributes actually changes , thinking sphinx sets delta = 1 which results in large number of unwanted queries being fired . can we do something to let sphinx know that there was no actual update.